# Error when decompiling utilizing Uncompyle6

Tags: python, reverse-engineering, decompiler

So after utilizing pyinstxtractor to get the PYC file, adding a magic number to the beggining of said file (it took hours to get to this point...) and finally trying to decompile it using Uncompyle6, I recieve the following error:

```
"C code is Python 1.0 - 1.2; can't handle yet"
```

I have no idea how to proceed... help

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your pyc is for version 1.0 - 1.2, so you made a mistake somewhere in getting to the pyc.

See https://github.com/rocky/python-xdis/blob/master/xdis/magics.py for information about Python magic numbers.

In general, if you have a problem decompiling any Python program, make sure that it can be disassembled and it looks reasonable. No Python decompiler will work if it's input isn't valid Python byte/word code.